# Paperclip save images as jpg with white background

Tags: imagemagick, paperclip, post-processing

I'd like to know how to convert png and gif files with alpha channel to jpg with white background with paperclip

I tried this but, it doesn't work

```
has_attached_file( 
  :photo, 
  :whiny => false, 
  :styles => { 
    :medium => ["300x300>", :jpg], 
    :thumb => ["100x100>", :jpg] 
  }, 
  :convert_options => { :all => '-alpha white -background white'}
)
```

It saves the file with the gray background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-alpha remove -background white` is preferable. `white` is not a valid argument for `-alpha`.

Answer (score 13):

here the solution

```
has_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => {
    :medium => ["300x300>",:jpg],
    :thumb => ["100x100>", :jpg]
  },
  :convert_options => {
    :all => '-background white -flatten +matte'
  }
```

Comment: It might resize the image not the way you want it to be, the suggestion form @Pat McGee works better for me

Comment: Same for me, @Pat McGee's answer is the correct one! This one brought us a lot of issues when used together with cropping/extending